# Return array after forEach loop (async) is finished

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now. I am trying to collect data from my database and push it to an array. When the loop is finished I want to return the array with the retrieved data. Now I managed to make an async forEach loop, but (as expected) I am receiving an empty array, because it doesn't wait for the function to end.

Here's my code:

```
StatusHandler.prototype.recover = async function recover(modelIds) {
  try {
    const items = [];
    modelIds.forEach(async (id) => {
      try {
        const query = {
          [this.modelId]: ObjectId(id),
          deleted: 'Y',
          xms_status: {
            $nin: [/inactive/, /maintenance/],
          },
        };
        const model = await this.Model.findOne(query);
        console.log(model); // Shows the correct data.
        items.push(model);
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }, this);
    return items; // Returns empty array
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

I saw some related questions and noticed I can use the `for..of` loop, but I can't use that because of thee Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide (it recommends `forEach` instead of `for..of`).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: But you can make this in a single query to fetch all the models instead of looping & pushing into the array. check if this works 
`var query = { $in: modelIds, deleted: 'Y', xms_status: { $nin: [/inactive/, /maintenance/],  }, };`

Comment: this is where a `for` loop would actually behave as you would like ... `for(let i = 0; i < modelIds.length; i++) { let id = modelIds[i]); .... rest of your code ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you loop over an array of IDs and use `findOne` to retrieve your objects, you could use something like this :

```
await this.Model.find({_id: {$in: modelIds}});
```

Also, instead of using `forEach` to push in an array, why don't you use `map` ?

I think you could do something like that :

```
async function recover(modelIds) {
  return modelsIds.map(async (modelId, i) => {
    const query = "..."; // your query with the id
    return await this.Model.findOne(query);
  })
}
```

And the surround your function call with `try/catch` to catch errors trhown during your function execution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am actually ashamed I haven't thought of that. :')